# The planar limit, self-duality and their relation to two dimensions

Tags: field-theory, yang-mills, ads-cft, duality, integrable-systems

In the lecture notes by [Beisert](http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs13/13HSInt/) on integrability, it is stated that integrability is a property mainly in two-dimensional field theories, with some higher-dimensional examples. As higher-dimensional examples he explicitly quotes the following two theories:

$$\begin{align}
&\bullet ~ ~ \mathcal{N}=4 ~ ~ \rm{super-Yang ~ Mills ~ theory} \\
&\bullet ~ ~ \rm{the ~ self-dual ~ Yang ~ Mills ~ theory ~ in ~ four ~ dimensions}
\end{align}$$

and he goes on to make the following statement:

***most of them have some implicit two-dimensionality (self-duality, planar limit)***.

I have tried to understand and figure out how self-duality and the planar limit are related and/or implied to two dimensions, but I have not made any progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is a complete answer, all I did was basically some data mining + use some sparse domain knowledge + tried to be mature enough to interpretate and correlate information. Anyways, here are my 5 cents...

Let us first set the ground here.

a) Self-duality and conformal symmetry are [closely related](https://cds.cern.ch/record/293244/files/9512130.pdf) in SDYM.

b) I'll take "planar limit" as the consequence of 't Hooft expansion over large N (colour number). This makes a [spectrum composed of single trace operators only](https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-9/9b6262785724ea2c8ba14d81324518d5). Also, see my key point 2.

Now, the key points are

1. The *implicit two-dimensionality* is related to how the [S-matrix factors out](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3494.pdf). Self-duality and its relation to conformal symmetry (or the self-dual "conformality"), plus the underlying symmetries that allows the S-matrix factorization over 2-body processes, might be what the author meant as implicit two-dimensionality regarding self-duality.
2. The planar limit greatly simplifies, since (and I quote [2](https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-9/9b6262785724ea2c8ba14d81324518d5)):
   "The gauge theory simplifies and exhibits string-like behaviour.The Feynman diagrams organise themselves into an expansion in topologies of the two-dimensional surfaces on which the diagrams can be written". So, here the *implicit two-dimensionality* might be related to the perturbative-sum-over-genus-like tractable approach that emerges.

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for the references and your answer. I will wait some more days to see if there will be a more explicit and/or thorough one and if not I will accept yours and of course award you the bounty

Comment: Thanks, and sorry that I can't help you some more. Seems like a fascinating topic and I'll sure tackle it one day. It's on my to do list (: